# Unknown Ether type 0x880a and 0x5524 in Wireshark capture

Tags: networking, ethernet, wireshark

Since last several days, task manager shows 200-300Kbps (with small b) receive networking at idle time without opening any application. Though I block all apps in firewall (except system PID 4), task manager shows same network activity. When I open Wireshark to check network packets it shows some weired network activity. Even this ether type `0x880a` and `0x5524` is not documented in [IEEE 802 Numbers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ieee-802-numbers/ieee-802-numbers.xhtml). Also that MAC address doesn't belong to any host of my Ethernet IPv4 subnetwork (/25). Here is the packet's metadata & data in plain text.

```
Source                Destination Protocol Length Sender IP address Info
Shenzhen_01:35:b2     Broadcast   0x880a   60                       Ethernet II

Ethernet II, Src: Shenzhen_01:35:b2 (50:0b:91:e1:35:b2), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
Data (46 bytes)

0000  00 6c 6f 6f 70 62 61 63 6b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   .loopback.......
0010  00 00 00 00 00 2d 36 35 06 5f 68 74 74 70 73 00   .....-65._https.
0020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00         ..............
    Data: 006c6f6f706261636b0000000000000000000000002d3635...
    [Length: 46]
```

[image: Ether Type 0x880a.PNG]

---

```
Source                Destination Protocol Length Sender IP address Type       Info
ChengduM_e9:e9:3d     Broadcast   0x5524   64                       0x5524     Ethernet II

Ethernet II, Src: ChengduM_e9:e9:3d (00:01:7a:e9:e9:3d), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
Data (50 bytes)

0000  80 00 00 01 7a e9 e9 3d 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 01   ....z..=........
0010  7a e9 e9 3d 00 00 00 13 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   z..=............
0020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0030  00 00                                             ..
    Data: 800000017ae9e93d00000000800000017ae9e93d00000013...
    [Length: 50]
```

[image: Ether Type 0x5524.PNG]

---

- **Question:** What are these unknown Ethernet packets? Are those malicious? Is ISP networking responsible for these network packets?

Comment: If you don't get answers here, also try https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note that the main registry of ethertypes is [maintained by IEEE](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/ethertype/eth.txt) – not that it helps much, as 0x880A is merely part of the "reserved for 802.3 Ethernet" range. Also, since it doesn't carry IP, your IPv4 subnetwork is quite irrelevant.

Comment: @dirkt I did not relate this problem with Reverse engineering. I'm afraid of MITM.

Comment: Keep unplugging stuff until you find the source. (It might be a Wi-Fi connected device.)

Comment: @grawity No WiFi, no other devices connected to Ethernet, just my PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your network contain any devices or network interface chipsets designed, manufactured, or sold by "Shenzhen zhong ju Fiber optical Co. Ltd"? Like maybe a fiber transceiver or GPON terminal or fiber SFP module or something?

This looks like some no-name vendor just squatted on an unassigned EtherType when creating a crappy proprietary broadcast-based status/discovery protocol. The only information it contains is "loopback", "-65", and "_https". It may be  advertising that its optical signal strength is -65dB, and that its management interface is reachable via HTTPS. It may even be trying to do loop detection or be trying to perform a loopback test.

It looks a lot more like a crappy no-name vendor doing something sloppy and nonstandard, rather than anything malicious.

Comment: Can you post a pcap with a lot more of these packets?

Comment: @Biswa I don’t know. Perhaps upload it wherever you want and post a link.